# Dataframe wrangling in r after Welch ANOVA post-hoc. Producing a dataframe from a pairwise.t.test

Tags: r, dataframe, data-wrangling

A bit of a data-wrangling question. I am performing a Welch ANOVA with a pairwise t-test post hoc. For example:

```
welch <- oneway.test(iris, formula = Petal.Width ~ Species)
ph <- pairwise.t.test(iris$Petal.Width, iris$Species, p.adjust.method = "bonferroni")
```

The ph object returns a list as the following...

```
                 setosa   versicolor
versicolor 3.764933e-57           NA
virginica  2.385524e-85 2.646251e-36
```

I now want a dataframe that looks like:

```
group1      group2       P      Sig
versicolor  setosa       0.000  **
virginica   setosa       0.000  **
virginica   versicolor   0.000  **
```

How can I manipulate this into a data frame that would look like the above? Where the asterix is representative of significance. I.e. P > 0.05 = "ns", P < 0.05 = "*", P < 0.01 = "**". In reality, my actual data has multiple 'Species' so it must be capable of determining the groups when species may be > 3.

Comment: The `broom` package provides `tidy` methods that the convert output objects of many functions from many packages to data frames in “standard” formats. I don’t know if it provides one for the Welch test, but it is definitely worth a look.  From which package do the functions you are using come?

Comment: Wow the broom package is great! Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using the `broom` package

```
welch <- oneway.test(iris, formula = Petal.Width ~ Species)
ph <- pairwise.t.test(iris$Petal.Width, iris$Species, p.adjust.method = "bonferroni")

library(broom)
df <- tidy(ph)
#add significance column
 df$Sig <- df$Sig
 df$Sig[df$p.value > 0.05] <- "ns"
 df$Sig[df$p.value <= 0.05] <- "*"
 df$Sig[df$p.value <= 0.01] <- "**"
 df
```

Output:

```
group1      group2     p.value       Sig
versicolor  setosa     3.764933e-57  ** 
virginica   setosa     2.385524e-85  ** 
virginica   versicolor 2.646251e-36  **
```

Answer (score 0):

You have already answered your own question. I'll just add a dplyr variant using `mutate()` and `case_when()`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(broom)

welch <- oneway.test(iris, formula = Petal.Width ~ Species)
ph <- pairwise.t.test(iris$Petal.Width, iris$Species, p.adjust.method = "bonferroni")

df <- ph |>
  tidy() |>
  mutate(
    Sig = case_when(
      p.value > 0.05 ~ "ns",
      p.value <= 0.01 ~ "**",
      p.value <= 0.05 ~ "*"
    )
  )
```

You will notice that I have changed the order of the formulas. This is due to the fact that `case_when()` applies them in order of appearance. If `<= 0.01` was below `<= 0.05`, it would not be applied to p values that already passed the earlier `<= 0.05` condition.